# Any way for matlab to sum an array according to specified bins NOT by for iteration? Best if there is buildin function for this

Tags: matlab, sum, histogram

For example, if

```
A = [7,8,1,1,2,2,2]; % the bins (or subscripts)
B = [2,1,1,1,1,1,2]; % the array
```

then the desired function "binsum" has two outputs, one is the bins, and the other is the sum. It is just adding values in B according to subscripts in A. For example, for 2, the sum is 1 + 1 + 2 = 4, for 1 it is 1 + 1 = 2.

```
[bins, sums] = binsum(A,B);

bins = [1,2,7,8]
sums = [2,4,2,1]
```

The elements in "bins" need not be ordered but must correspond to elements in "sums". This can surely be done by "for" iterations, but **"for" iteration is not desired**, because there is a performance concern. It is best if there is a build in function for this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting `bins` and `sums` from `A` and `B`. Can you explain the operation?

Comment: @beaker Thanks for comment. I added explanation. It is adding values in B according to bins in A. For example, for 2, the sum is 1 + 1 + 2 = 4, for 1 it is 1 + 1 = 2. So in output, 1 in "bins" corresponds to 2 in "sum", and 2 in "bins" corresponds to 4 in "sums".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is another job for [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)

```
A = [7,8,1,1,2,2,2]; % the bins (or subscripts)
B = [2,1,1,1,1,1,2]; % the array

sums = accumarray(A.', B.').';
bins = unique(A);
```

Results:

```
>> bins
bins =

   1   2   7   8

sums =

   2   4   0   0   0   0   2   1
```

The index in `sums` corresponds to the bin value, so `sums(2) = 4`. You can use `nonzeros` to remove the unused bins so that `bins(n)` corresponds to `sums(n)`

```
sums = nonzeros(sums).';

sums =

   2   4   2   1
```

or, to generate this form of `sums` in one line:

```
sums = nonzeros(accumarray(A.', B.')).';
```

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is to use [`sparse`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) and then [`find`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html).

- Assuming `A` contains positive integers,

  ```
  [bins, ~, sums] = find(sparse(A, 1, B));
  ```

  This works because `sparse` automatically adds values (third input) for matching positions (as defined by the first two inputs).
- If `A` can contain arbitrary values, you also need a call to [`unique`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), and `find` can be replaced by [`nonzeros`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nonzeros.html):

  ```
  [bins, ~, labels]= unique(A);
  sums = nonzeros(sparse(labels, 1, B));
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `sort` and `cumsum`:

```
[s,I]=sort(A);
c=cumsum(B(I));
k= [s(1:end-1)~=s(2:end) true];
sums = diff([0 c(k)])
bins = s(k)
```