# In matlab how to sum rows of a matrix according to specified bins/subscripts in a non-iteration manner?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum

This question generalizes the previous one [Any way for matlab to sum an array according to specified bins NOT by for iteration? Best if there is buildin function for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45661195/any-way-for-matlab-to-sum-an-array-according-to-specified-bins-not-by-for-iterat). I am not sure, but I tried and the answers in previous post seem not to work with matrices.

For example, if

```
A = [7,8,1,1,2,2,2]; % the bins or subscripts
B = [2,1; ...
     1,1; ...
     1,1; ...
     2,0; ...
     3,1; ...
     0,2; ...
     2,4]; % the matrix
```

then the desired function "binsum" has two outputs, one is the bins, and the other is the accumulated row vectors. It is adding rows in B according to subscripts in A. For example, for 2, the sum is [3,1] + [0,2] + [2,4] = [5,6], for 1 it is [1,1] + [2,0] = [3,1].

[bins, sums] = binsum(A,B);

```
bins = [1,2,7,8]
sums = [2,1;
        1,1;
        3,1;
        5,6]
```

The first method [accumarray](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) says its "val" argument can only be a scalar or vector. The second method [spare](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html?searchHighlight=sparse&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) seems not to accept a vector as the value "v" for each tuple (i,j) neither. So I have to post for help again, and it is still not desired to use iterations to go over the columns of B to do this.

I am using 2017a. Many thanks again!

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks. I am using 2017a.

Comment: If nothing else, you can iterate over the columns of `B` and use the previous solution, e.g. `accumarray(A.', B(:,1))` for the first column of `sums`.

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks a lot for help. B could be thousands of columns.

Comment: @beaker Thanks for your help!

Comment: Shouldn't the last row of the sums  be `[5,7]` instead of `[5,6]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to do that is using matrix multiplication:

```
bins = unique(A);
sums = (A==bins.')*B;
```

The above is memory-expensive, as it builds an intermediate `logical` matrix of size *M*×*N*, where *M* is the the number of bins and *N* is the length of `A`. Alternatively, you can build that matrix as `sparse logical` to save memory:

```
[bins, ~, labels] = unique(A);
sums = sparse(labels, 1:numel(A), true)*B;
```

Answer (score 0):

A method base on `sort` and `cumsum`:

```
[s,I]=sort(A);
c=cumsum(B(I,:));
k= [s(1:end-1)~=s(2:end) true];
sums = diff([zeros(1,size(B,2)); c(k,:)])
bins=s(k)
```